# select employee with their manager in 2 table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database, one with employees and the second with managers. I want to  select  all employees under a specified manager.

Employee table

```
id  name
1   shivam
2   ravi
```

Manager  table

```
id empId managerId
1    1     2
2    2     1
```

And I'd like this type of result

```
id  name  managername
1  shivam ravi
2  ravi   shivam
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link where I ran the code https://sqltest.net/#686252

If a table was created like this:

```
create table employee(
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(20),
    primary key (id)
);

create table manager(
    id int auto_increment,
    empId int,
    managerId int,
    primary key (id)
);


insert into employee (name) values ('shivam'), ('ravi');
insert into manager (empId,managerId) values (1,2),(2,1);
```

then you could get the result you want with this statement:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e2.name managername from 
employee as e
join manager as m on m.empId = e.id
join employee as e2 on e2.id = m.managerId;
```

Here are my results:

```
id  name    managername
1   shivam  ravi
2   ravi    shivam
```